# Nodejs File get deleted before sending response (res.send)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filesystems

Here the problem is File get deleted from the server before sending a response to the client and display error as no image on this path.

```
 // Here some code 
 res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../image", `/${response.id}.png`));

   // Delete image from server
    fs.unlink(imagePath, function (err) {
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log('File deleted!');
     })
```

Comment: You should put your `unlink` code in the callback of `sendFile`. Otherwise you get the behavior you are seeing, the file gets unlinked before it can be transferred.

Comment: Thanks, got your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to monitor the callback to `res.sendFile()` so you know when the sending is actually done before you can safely delete your file.

`res.sendFile()` is asynchronous so it returns before the job is done, thus you were deleting the file before `res.sendFile()` was done.  Use the callback to know when it's actually done.

```
   let fname = path.join(__dirname, "../../image", `/${response.id}.png`);
   res.status(200).sendFile(fname, err => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
      }
      fs.unlink(fname, function(err) => {
         // log any error
         if (err) {
             console.log(err);
         }
      });
   });
```

Note: When you pass a callback to `res.sendFile()` you have to manually handle an error condition and send an error response, retry, send alternative content, etc... to send some appropriate response.

I'm also wondering why you're sending one filename and attempting to delete a different one.  Wouldn't it make sense to use the same local variable for the filename you're sending and the one you're deleting?

Comment: Yes, I'm deleting the same file after generating and saving into database. So, now I can use the same local variable to get the path. Previously it didn't strike.

Comment: fs.unlink(imagePath) should be changed to fs.unlinkSync(imagePath) right? Or else an error is thrown since a callback is not passed.

Comment: @NandunThilinaBandara - Back in 2015 (when this answer was written), if you didn't care about the error for `fs.unlink()`, you could skip the callback.  That is no longer the case so you do need to pass the callback.  You would never want to use `fs.unlinkSync()` on a server because that's a blocking API that hurts the scalability of your server.  I updated the code to pass a callback to `fs.unlink()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh alright. Thank you for the response and the update.